# Unable to run .cshtml pages on Windows 2008 IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

I have created an ASP.Net C# website using Visual Studio with Razor v2. I published it to my live server, but the pages do not process the code. The pages are .cshtml pages.

- The server is a Windows 2008 Server with IIS7.
- The Application Pool is .NET Framework v4.0.30319.
- .cshtml is listed in MIME Types as text/html
- *.cshtml is NOT listed in the Handler Mapping.

I am going to guess that I need to add .cshtml to the handler mappings, but I do not know how that needs to set up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I take the .cshtml out of the Mime Types and try to run the page I get:
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET project? ASP.NET MVC web apps should be accessed via certain URL patterns (like `controller/action`), and raw .cshtml files are never accessible in URL, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view